# The set of pts in a measurable set where a sequence of measurable functions converges is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we have a sequence of measurable functions $\{f_n\}$ defined on a measurable set $E$.  Define $E_0$ to be the set of points in $E$ at which $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges.  Is $E_0$ measurable?

My problem is that we don't have the notion of Cauchy sequences.  If we did, the solution would be pretty short.  But I'm afraid I will end up with a complicated $\epsilon-\delta$ mess.  What could I do in this situation?

My understanding is that these functions converge pointwise at each of these points $x \in E_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Usually one works with $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ to define the set $E_0$. If you have not worked with Cauchy, that seems perhaps a bit out of reach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use that $lim\ inf\ f_n$ and $lim\ sup\ f_n$ are both measurable.

Comment: Beware of answering in significantly fewer words than the original poster used to ask their Question.

Comment: And why is that?

Comment: just to be clear, they are both measurable as they are part of the original $\{f_n\}$ and they are essentially what $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges to, correct?

Comment: A terse statement is apt to be less clear to your Readers than you intend it to be.  Better to give a fuller reasoned argument/explanation than to take a "bread crumb" approach to responding.  While a one-liner like this might be easily put into a Coment, the Answer box is intended to collect excellent mathematical content that will be helpful to future Readers.  See [How do I write a good answer?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the FAQ.

Comment: @NinosławCiszewski I'm not sure I understood what you mean by being a part of $\{f_n\}$. Nonetheless you can make it precise using the definition of $lim\ inf f_n(x) = sup_{k \ge 1}\ inf_{n \ge k}\ f_n(x)$. Hint: Prove that $g(x) = inf_{n \ge 1}\ f_n(x)$ is measurable.